# Alamofire - how to get the number of records in the table

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, alamofire

I have this code:

```
func downloadDataRanking(completed: @escaping () -> ()){
        Alamofire.request(rankingGroupUrlToShow, method: .get, parameters: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                let jsonResponse = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if (jsonResponse.isEmpty || jsonResponse != "{}") {
                    if(jsonResponse["ranking"]["grupy"].count > 0){
                        let grupy = jsonResponse["ranking"]["grupy"].array
                        if (grupy!.count > 0) {
                            for i in 0...(grupy?.count)! - 1 {


                                var tablicaGraczy = 0
                                if (grupy![i]["grupy"].array != nil){
                                    tablicaGraczy = grupy![i]["grupy"].array?.count  // ilość graczy @@@@ tu jest problem
                                }

                                let graczeRankingu = grupy![i]["grupy"].array
                                print("graczeRankingu: \(graczeRankingu)")

                                if tablicaGraczy > 0 {



                                    DispatchQueue.main.async { // watek od rysowania interface
                                        for ii in 0...(tablicaGraczy) - 1 {
                                            print("GRACZ: \(graczeRankingu![ii]["czasGry"]) ii \(graczeRankingu![ii]["liczbaZdobytychPunktow"]) ii \(graczeRankingu![ii]["email"]) ii \(graczeRankingu![ii]["zdjecieZFacebooka"]) ii \(graczeRankingu![ii]["imieINazwisko"]) ii \(graczeRankingu![ii]["dataZdobyciaPunktow"]) ii \(graczeRankingu![ii]["zakonczonaGra"]) ii ")


                                            var dataZdobyciaPunktow = ""
                                            if (graczeRankingu![ii]["dataZdobyciaPunktow"]["year"].int != nil){
                                                dataZdobyciaPunktow = "\(graczeRankingu![ii]["dataZdobyciaPunktow"]["dayOfMonth"].int!).\(graczeRankingu![ii]["dataZdobyciaPunktow"]["month"].int!).\(graczeRankingu![ii]["dataZdobyciaPunktow"]["year"].int!)"

                                            }


                                            var imieINazwisko = ""
                                            if (graczeRankingu![ii]["imieINazwisko"].string?.isEmpty == false){
                                                imieINazwisko = graczeRankingu![ii]["imieINazwisko"].string!
                                            }

                                            var zdjecieZFacebooka = ""
                                            if (graczeRankingu![ii]["zdjecieZFacebooka"].string?.isEmpty == false){
                                                zdjecieZFacebooka = graczeRankingu![ii]["zdjecieZFacebooka"].string!
                                            }

                                            var email = ""
                                            if (graczeRankingu![ii]["email"].string?.isEmpty == false){
                                                email = graczeRankingu![ii]["email"].string!
                                            }

                                            var liczbaZdobytychPunktow = ""
                                            if (graczeRankingu![ii]["liczbaZdobytychPunktow"].string?.isEmpty == false){
                                                liczbaZdobytychPunktow = graczeRankingu![ii]["liczbaZdobytychPunktow"].string!
                                            }

                                            var czasGry = ""
                                            if (graczeRankingu![ii]["czasGry"].string?.isEmpty == false){
                                                czasGry = graczeRankingu![ii]["czasGry"].string!
                                            }
                                        }
                                        print("WYNIKI: \(self.items)")
                                        completed()

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
    }
```

The above code has:
a) download data from the selected URL using Alamofire
b) check if the downloaded table is empty
c) save downloaded values to variables

I have problem with this code:

```
var tablicaGraczy = 0
if (grupy![i]["grupy"].array != nil){
tablicaGraczy = grupy![i]["grupy"].array?.count  
}
```

I get an error message: Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

This code is to check whether the number of records has an array - and if it is empty, assign it to 0

btw. Do you write to variables:  imieINazwisko, zdjecieZFacebooka, email, liczbaZdobytychPunktow, czasGry - is your opinion done correctly? Do you know a better solution to this?

Comment: your Response is dictionary or array ? Can you post your response or share your url if its not private ? Also you should not force unwrap ( ! ), instead use if let or guard let.

Comment: yes, this is my json: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/json.php . what unwrap are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better practice don't do JSON parsing in request method only, you should pass the response in completion block and there do the operations.

Also, read about how to unwrap using if let/guard let. : https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/if-let-if-var-guard-let-and-defer-statements-in-swift-4f87fe857eb6

This is APIHelper Class :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class APIHelper: NSObject{

    func downloadDataRanking(completion: @escaping ([String: Any], Bool) -> ()){
        guard let requestUrl = URL.init(string: "http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/json.php") else { return }
        Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get, parameters: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result{
                case .success:
                    let statusCode: Int = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                    switch statusCode{
                    case 200:
                        if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{
                            completion(json, true)
                        }
                        break
                    default:
                        completion([String: Any](), false)
                        break
                    }
                    break
                case .failure:
                    completion([String: Any](), false)
                    break
                }
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller call this fucntion :

```
func fetchData(){
        APIHelper().downloadDataRanking { (response, success) in
            if success{
                print("SUCCESS : downloadDataRanking")
                if !response.isEmpty{
                    if let ranking = response["ranking"] as? [String: Any], let grupy = ranking["grupy"] as? [[String: Any]], !grupy.isEmpty {
                        print("ranking : \(ranking)")
                        print("grupy : \(grupy)")


                        for object in grupy{
                            if let gracze = object["gracze"] as? [[String: Any]], !gracze.isEmpty{
                                for objectGracze in gracze{
                                    print("objectGracze : \(objectGracze)")
                                    if let zdjecieZFacebooka = objectGracze["zdjecieZFacebooka"] as? String, let email = objectGracze["email"] as? String, let czasGry = objectGracze["czasGry"] as? String{
                                        print("zdjecieZFacebooka : \(zdjecieZFacebooka)")
                                        print("email : \(email)")
                                        print("czasGry : \(czasGry)")
                                    }

                                    if let dataZdobyciaPunktow = objectGracze["dataZdobyciaPunktow"] as? [String: Any]{
                                        print("dataZdobyciaPunktow : \(dataZdobyciaPunktow)")

                                        if let year = dataZdobyciaPunktow["year"] as? Int, let month = dataZdobyciaPunktow["month"] as? Int{
                                            print("year : \(year)")
                                            print("month : \(month)")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }else{
                print("ERROR : downloadDataRanking")
            }
        }
    }
```

In this function you can get all JSON values. For example, I am getting ranking, grupy, zdjecieZFacebooka, email and czasGry.

Comment: extra :) sharad chauhan - it's working :) Could you tell me how to adapt to your code, in the case of such a json: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/json2.php - variable dataZdobyciaPunktow and display it?

Comment: @ŁukaszBetta Updated the answer. But you should understand how it's been done.